# Combine default case with other cases

Tags: swift, enums

Given the following enum in C# and a switch/case to return the a border color of a textbox according its state for example.

```
enum TextboxState {
 Default,
 Error
}

switch(foo) {
 default:
 case TextboxState.Default:  return Color.Black;
 case TextboxState.Error:    return Color.Red;
}
```

So basically I define a real and not just by convention default state aka `TextboxState.Default` by adding the `default:` case. I just want to do this to prevent future breaking changes if new values are added to the enum.

According to the Swift book this is not possible:

> “If it is not appropriate to provide a switch case for every possible
>   value, you can define a default catch-all case to cover any values
>   that are not addressed explicitly. This catch-all case is indicated by
>   the keyword default, and **must always appear last**.”

The paragraph is quite clear about that, so I assume my pattern above does not apply to Swift or do I miss something? Is there another way to archive something like the above code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `fallthrough` to do that, by moving the shared behavior in the `default` case, and using `fallthrough` in all cases for which you want the shared behavior to occur.

For example, if this is your enum (added a 3rd case to show it can handle multiple fall throughs):

```
enum TextboxState {
    case Default
    case Error
    case SomethingElse
}
```

you can format the `switch` statement as follows:

```
switch(foo) {
case TextboxState.Error:
    return UIColor.redColor()

case TextboxState.Default:
    fallthrough

case TextboxState.SomethingElse:
    fallthrough

default: 
    return UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

Each `fallthrough` moves the execution point to the next case, up to the `default` case.

Comment: For reference, the fallthrough is documented under the switch-section here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `default:` line from your `switch`. Even if you someday add additional cases to your enum, the Swift compiler will complain if you don't add corresponding cases to every `switch` that uses the enum. And FYI, you don't need to specify the `TextboxState.` before the `case` values in the `switch`, because the compiler knows that `foo` is a `TextboxState`. The resulting code would be:

```
switch(foo) {
    case .Default:  return Color.Black;
    case .Error:    return Color.Red;
}
```

although, for consistency, I'd put the `.Error` case before the `.Default` one.